# Editing contact picture programmatically on receiving the call , does Apple allows that?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am developing the App, When i receive the call ,I am changing the contact picture of that person who has called , I am fetching his number from the server , i know i cannot access the incoming number ,so by developing this kind of application will apple approve my App ?

I am not violating any Guideline or Rules ,but i just want to know does Apple allows this changing the contact picture of person programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [change a contact picture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210), check the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744).

About that idea of doing something when you get a call, your app can't be notified when you get an incoming call, there's no API for that, so there's no way of doing this the way you are planning.

Comment: I can get notification by CTCallCenter only thing i should wake up the app from background or i can use the push notification for this .I have changed the contact picture but i just want to know does apple recommends doing like this ?